# Pycharm console startup script not working

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.4 on a Macbook running Mavericks. Under `Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Console > Python Console` there is a text area to input a starting script. Initially it contains `import sys;` followed by a print statement that prints the file path of the Python framework as well as the file path of the current file. However, when I alter or delete the print statements in this section, and then hit apply and OK, nothing changes in my python console output. I have tried restarting Pycharm and then running a `hello world` program, but the initial starting script output is still there.

I am just running a simple hello world program, with one package and two files (the other being the default `__init__.py`). How can I alter the starting script correctly?

Comment: I modified the contents of the startup script section under my python console, then hit "reload" on the console.  This did nothing to my suprise!  However, I found that closing the console with the big red X and then reopening it did cause it to run the code from that block.  Hopefully that'll be helpful.

Comment: Do you mean the console in the "Python Console" window or the one in the "Debug" window?  It seems that the starting script specified is not run upon starting the "Debug" console.

Comment: And why is that, I wonder?

Comment: Does anyone know why the "Starting script" is not loaded in debug more?

Answer (score 4):

You want to change the startup scripts then. Change called "Starting Script":

[image]

Comment: Where is "Starting Script"? I don't see it in the screenshot.

Comment: @flow2k It's the title of the edit box where the code is.