# How do I change the startup script in console in PyCharm's debugger?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I want to change this (debugger console):
[image]

to this (startup console):
[image]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28162279/pycharm-console-startup-script-not-working

Comment: Yes, it is related but different. There is a startup script for the python console in non-debug mode; I am able to change that. But when you run the debugger, the startup script  of the console in the debugger does not change. They seem to have two different sources